# NSApplicationPresentationOptions doesn't work with FIREBREATH

Tags: cocoa, plugins, kiosk, firebreath, nsapplication

I am trying to customize user experience from the plugin I am working on, my goal is to provide a kiosk style using the options available in COCOA NSApplication, the code is like following:

```
// Hide the dock tile and the menu bar:
NSApplicationPresentationOptions options = 
    NSApplicationPresentationHideDock +  NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar;

[NSApp setPresentationOptions:options];
```

I have tested this code using a normal cocoa application and it works fine but when I embed this code in a function inside a "Firebreath PlugIn" nothing happens although the firebreath builds correctly and the other functions I have works normally.

some ideas? this is about system security restrictions maybe?? if so how to enable it?  I don't know why this doesn't work if other cocoa functions works fine.

I am developing over Mac OS X Lion with XCODE 4.2

Comment: Change the plus `+` to a pipe `|`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you can't get tot he NSApplication because you are in a different process; you might be able to create a fake one or something like that with a new NSWindow to make it work, but since you're in a different process from the browser there is no way to access the browser's NSApp or other similar objects.